# Versioning module in python missing

Tags: python

When i compile s3cmd, I found Versioning module is missing, stacktrace as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./s3cmd", line 1983, in <module>
    from S3.S3 import S3
  File "/home/chutong/s3cmd.svn/S3/S3.py", line 29, in <module>
    from Versioning import Versioning
ImportError: No module named Versioning
```

I tried to check online and there is not much resource? Can someone please help? Thanks

Comment: What package is S3 on your installation? I can't find a python package named simply 'S3'.

Comment: EDIT: Ok, never mind, I think I found it, looks like it's s3cmd ... checking ...

Answer (score 0):

I just checked [the source for s3cmd](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd) on github. It appears it no longer imports this module nor does it contain a module named Versioning in its code tree.

Without more information I can't tell, but what I would suspect is you have a version mismatch, perhaps one version installed in your Python environment and another one locally.

It's a bit odd that it's raising the exception from an SVN directory, but like I say, will need more information about your execution environment to make any headway. Things like current directory, a dump of sys.path, that sort of thing.

But if it's possible, you might try updating the installed version and trying again. Looks like the library has had some significant updates since the version you appear to be using.